# What are the quota and limits for Intelligent document quality processor in Google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

Basically, I would like to know the maximum page limit for processing a document via Document quality processor in GCP. Thanks in Advance.
When I tried a document with 6 pages, it throws an error that the pages should be 5 but got 6. Need to understand on the limits of quality processor as that information is not available in the documentation.

Comment: Looks like 5 is a common limit for the majority of processors (as we can find in the documentation) and you're right no such info for https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_doc-quality-processor

Comment: Fill out and submit [Doc AI Processors Access Request Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc_6s8jsHLZWWE0aSX0bdmk24XDoPiE_oq5enDApLcp1VKJ-Q/viewform?gxids=7826) if you have not yet done this, to have access on the feature. But if you have already access to the feature "Intelligent Document Quality Processor" you can contact [GCP support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support) to ask for further details on the limits of the processor.

Answer (score 0):

For Intelligent Document Quality, the limits are 5 pages for Online/Sync Processing and 100 for Batch/Async Processing. (This has now been added to the documentation)

You can view [Document AI platform-wide Quotas & Limits](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/quotas) and [Processor-specific Quotas & Limits for all processors](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/quotas#processor_limits) in the documentation.